# Average distance to the top half of a circle's circumference

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I'm working on a problem for my PhD that involves finding an expression for the average distance of every point inside a circle to the top half of the circumference of the circle.

Using basic trigonometry and WolframAlpha I've figured out that this distance $z$ for a given point $P=(r,\theta)$ inside a circle with radius $R$ is given by:

$$z=\sqrt{R^2-r^2\cos^2(\theta)}-r\sin(\theta)$$

[Visual aid for the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urc6y.png)

My issue is with the next step. I assume I'm supposed to integrate this expression over the entire circle and then divide it by the area of the circle, that is:

$$z=\frac{\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{R^2-r^2\cos^2(\theta)}-r\sin(\theta) d\theta dr}{\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}r d\theta dr}$$

When I tried to estimate this value using Excel with randomly generated points inside a unit circle (I am aware of the [Disk Point Picking problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html) so I used their suggestion to generate random points), the answer I got was around 0.9. However, when doing the calculation with the area on the denominator, the answer I got for the unit circle was 1.803, which seems to be wrong intuitively. I managed to obtain a very close value to my estimation (0.90143) by dividing not by the area but by $\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta dr$, but I can't find an explanation as to why this is the integral to use here. So which is the correct way to calculate this average distance without resorting to a numerical solution?

I'm also aware that a similar problem, the average distance from the center of the circle, isn't so trivial. The average distance is actually $\frac{2R}{3}$ and not $\frac{R}{2}$, but I honestly don't understand very well how it works.

Comment: This seems to mean you are looking for *vertical* distance, not *closest* distance, right?

Comment: I think you are missing an extra factor of $r$ in the numerator's integral.
The density for the uniform distribution over the disk of radius $R$, in polar coordinates, is $f(r, \theta) \, dr \, d\theta = \frac{1}{\pi R^2}r \, dr \, d\theta$. So if you want the average of $g(r, \theta)$ with respect to this distribution, you want
$$\frac{1}{\pi R^2}\int_0^{R} \int_0^{2\pi} g(r, \theta) r \, d\theta \, dr,$$
rather than
$$\frac{1}{\pi R^2}\int_0^{R} \int_0^{2\pi} g(r, \theta) \, d\theta \, dr.$$

Comment: @MPW yes, I'm looking for the vertical distance to the top half of the circumference.

Comment: @angryavian I figured out the issue with my numeric approximation. Using your formula the integral resolves to $\frac{8R^3}{3}$, which means the average distance to the top of the circumference is $\frac{8R}{3\pi}$ or around 0.8488. The reason for the slight difference was that I wasn't using the correct transformation when generating random points. I was converting to x,y coordinates correctly, but the input $(r,\theta)$ was wrong. Thanks for the help!